# MODX - Getting "pagetitle" and other info from siblings

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I need to figure out a way to add information from sibling pages to my template file

Here is an image of the file structure (the red items are the siblings whos info I need to access inside my template):

[image]

Here is the tpl file code that I am using:

```
[[+total:isequalto=`1`:then=`<div class="equalHeightListItem full_width[[+idx:isequalto=`1`:then=` column-last`]]">`:else=``]][[+total:isequalto=`2`:then=`<div class="equalHeightListItem one_half[[+idx:isequalto=`2`:then=` column-last`]]">`:else=``]][[+total:isequalto=`3`:then=`<div class="equalHeightListItem one_third[[+idx:isequalto=`3`:then=` column-last`]]">`:else=``]][[+total:isequalto=`4`:then=`<div class="equalHeightListItem one_half[[+idx:isequalto=`2`:then=` column-last`]][[+idx:isequalto=`4`:then=` column-last`]]">`:else=``]]
    <figure class="projectImg bwWrapper icon-box7">
        <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">
            <div class="operations productImage" style="max-width: 100%; background-image: url('[[+tv.products.category.img]]')"></div>
        </a>
        <div class="projectDesc equalHeightListItemInner operations">
            <h4><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+menutitle:default=`[[+pagetitle]]`]]</a></h4>
            <p>[[+introtext]]</p>

            <div><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="magicmore corpLink">Read More</a></div>

            <!-- I need to add sibling info here -->

        </div>                
    </figure>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I use `pdoResources` (which similar to `getResources`, but faster). Place this code in instead `<!-- I need to add sibling info here -->` and this is would help.

```
[[pdoResources?
    &parents=`[[+id]]`
    &depth=`1`
    &tpl=`your_sibling_row_tpl`
]]
```